# Regex extraction issue on bigger string

Tags: python, regex

Following regex works for smaller dataset

```
(r'Taxi* ([0-9.]+)',k,re.IGNORECASE)
```

But when I run the same on a bigger dataset it doesn't work.

e.g.

```
k=''Goa return Taxi ID: 170618970'
```

works fine.

but on a much bigger dataset the same pattern is not recognized.

Comment: how are we supposed to reproduce that without your dataset? or an extract where there's a problem?

Comment: This might be an issue with line breaks, try adding the flag `re.MULTILINE`: `(r'Taxi* ([0-9.]+)',k,re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: `Taxi* ([0-9.]+)` will never match `ID:`

Comment: "Hi how are you,hope you are doing fine "This regards booking return Taxi ID: 17061897084 tried calling response .We really sorry inconvenience booking XYZAS baggage .If would like add check baggage would pay extra charges details zxcvsdfsds soon possible .... For assistance, please write us." dataset is like this

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not glob like pattern matching :

- `Taxi*` matches `Tax`, `Taxi`, `Taxii`, etc.

maybe you wanted

- `Taxi.*`
- `.` : for any character (except newline by default)
- `*` : 0 or more times